# GNU make: Generate rules with transformed targets (without eval)

Tags: gnu-make

For instance, from variable:

```
files = dirx/a.cc diry/b.cc dirz/b.cc
```

I want to effectively have these rules: **(without resorting to define/eval)**

```
a_a.o: dirx/a.cc
b_b.o: diry/b.cc
c_c.o: dirz/c.cc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems unlikely, but this makefile does what you want:

**Makefile**

```
VPATH := dirx:diry:dirz
SRCS := a.cc b.cc c.cc
OBJS := $(foreach src,$(SRCS),$(basename $(src))_$(basename $(src)).o)

.PHONY: all clean

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o: $$(basename $$(subst _,.,$$*)).cc
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

all: $(OBJS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

With directories and files set up as per your example:

```
$ ls -R
.:
dirx  diry  dirz  Makefile

./dirx:
a.cc

./diry:
b.cc

./dirz:
c.cc
```

it runs like:

```
$ make
g++   -c -o a_a.o dirx/a.cc
g++   -c -o b_b.o diry/b.cc
g++   -c -o c_c.o dirz/c.cc
```

Cribs: -

- [VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html)
- [foreach](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html)
- [basename](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html)
- [subst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)
- [.SECONDEXPANSION](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html)

Comment: Another alternative is to use automatically regenerated included makefiles.  For a complete set of blog posts on "metaprogramming" in makefiles see http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/